# 4-graviton vertex of which one is an emitting graviton

Tags: general-relativity, feynman-diagrams, gravitational-waves, qft-in-curved-spacetime, effective-field-theory

For a four graviton vertex function, suppose $h_{\alpha\beta}h_{\gamma\delta}h_{\varepsilon\zeta}h_{00}$, of which $h_{00}$ is the emitting graviton to infinity. Now if we associate four-momenta $p_1$, p2, p3 and p4, respectively with the four graviton fields, does the $h_{00}$ emitting graviton has the four-momenta $p_4$, or only a component $p_4^{0}$ or $p_4^{i}$? Also is an emitting graviton to infinity always refer to $h_{00}$? Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Which theory is this?

Comment: this is massless spin-2 graviton, the effective field theory of general relativity in its classical limit.

Comment: Any reference? Quantum? Renormalisable? Mercury perihelion precession?